# Белые линии в адаптивной галерее

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, responsive

У меня есть на сайте галерея, в которой сетка выглядит таким образом:
[пример сетки](http://prntscr.com/91vdbh)

Посмотреть можно перейдя по этой ссылке [ссылка на пример работа](http://bitrix.fixaradesign.com/ru/)

В чем загвоздка: 
иногда при изменении размера экрана между картинками появляются белые линии (на сайте ссылка 1 вы сможете это увидеть если будете менять размер экрана, не могу третью ссылку вставить в связи с тем что репутация ниже 10).

Основная версия - картинки высчитываются в дробном значении и из-за этого появляются белые линии и решить это не представляется возможным (слова программистов).

Вопрос: можно ли это как то решить с сохранением сетки по примеру и без белых линий?

<s>пока писал пост пришла в голову мысль, что если картинкам самим добавлять размер (высоту)? (проверил, не работает).</s>

к примеру:

если большая картинка 443px
значит маленькие должны быть 221.5px

Answer (score 1):

Да потому что у вас все через `position:absolute` в котором неровные значения. Решить это все возможно и вариантов несколько:

1. Оборачивать некоторые дивы,что бы не было неровных значений
2. Табличная верстка(это мне кажется более сложный вариант).

Я думаю есть еще варианты просто нужно подумать